# Better way to create arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an array in Javascript with a size that is equivalent to the number of times a certain class is found in the DOM, and then iterate through it to grab the text from an input field present in that class.  I can easily do this like so:

```
var count = 0;
$('.className').each(function() {
    count++;
});
var classes = new Array(count);
count = 0;
$('.className input[type=text]').each(function() {
    classes[count++] = $(this).val();
});
```

This looks like a lot of code for what seems to be a relatively simple task.  Is there a more efficient or less lengthy way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: There are obviously many possible improvements but I don't think this code does what you want it to do.

Comment: You don't need to initialize arrays, they're dynamic, just create an empty one, and start filling it up.

Comment: @dystroy it goes without saying that I am new to Javascript, however the code does currently work the way I want it to.

Comment: @MichaelParker: Then this sounds more like [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than stack overflow.

Comment: @MattBurland I didn't even know that existed.  It does look like a better place to post this kind of question to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want this :

```
var classes = $('.className input[type=text]').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get();
```

But it's a guess : it's not clear why you start by counting all elements of the class and then iterate on the inputs.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  The reason I counted the elements before creating my array was because I didn't know you could create arrays with an unspecified size.  Still learning.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct an array of elements directly from your selector via the [makeArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/) function, then transform the result using a `map`.

```
var classes = $.makeArray($('.className input[type=text]')).map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [`map` function](http://api.jquery.com/map/), then [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) if you need a pure array:

```
var values = $('.className input[type=text]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`each` passes the index, so you don't need to do it yourself:

```
var classes = [];
$('.className input[type=text]').each(function(index, value) {
    classes[index] = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are dynamic and therefore don't need to be initialized. Create a new array, loop through the inputs and push the values to the new array:

```
var classes = [];
$('.className input[type=text]').each(function(idx, elem) {
    classes.push($(elem).val());
});
```